# Chain dynamic input/output rules in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to create a pipeline where a small chain of rules are ran on a dynamic number of files output by an earlier rule using output. However, I am getting the following error: "wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:".

This suggests to me that what I am trying to do is not currently supported. Here is a pseudo example of what I am trying to do:

```
rule a:
    input: "my static file.txt"
    output: dynamic('my/path/{id}.txt')

rule b:
    input: dynamic('my/path/{id}.txt')
    output: dynamic('my/path/{id}.reprocessed.txt')

rule c:
    input: dynamic('my/path/{id}.reprocessed.txt')
    output: 'gather.txt'
```

Running snakemake with

```
rule all:
    input: dynamic('my/path/{id}.txt')
```

Works without any issues, but when I run snakemake with:

```
rule all:
    input: dynamic('my/path/{id}.reprocessed.txt')
```

I get the error: "wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:"

Is this feature supported? Has anyone successfully made such a chain? Any considerations I need to take into account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by removing the dynamic statement from rule b.

Comment: is it possible to have a rule with dynamic and non-dynamic output files?

Comment: I had a similar issue and created two rules: one w/ dynamic and one w/ non-dynamic